# React Query- How to recall api from other component

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have component A,I call react query inside,I have component B, it make update data of api.
How when i update data from api B will it call back api to update new data.
Thanks

I don't know how to do it, please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using mutations from react-query, you can call `queryClient.invalidateQueries()` from within the `onSuccess` handler as described in the [documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/invalidations-from-mutations).

That looks like this:

```
const mutationFn = () => fetch(...);

const ComponentB = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn,
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['query-key'] })
    },
  });

  ...
}
```

If you're not using mutations, it is basically the same but without the `onSuccess` handler.

```
const doRequest = () => fetch(...);

const ComponentB = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()

  const performUpdate = async () => {
    await doRequest();
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['query-key'] });
  };

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked
I have a question, when I use getQueryData, it don't get data, but if I click a button, It can get

Comment: Glad it worked. There is not much I can say except that probably the data isn't requested/cached yet when you call `getQueryData`. You'll have to share some code for us to see, but preferably, in a new SO question.

Comment: After executing the onClick function the component is re-rendered and useQuery is returning the new data ([]). But it seems like React is discarding this render because the state did not change. After that a notification from the cache comes in, telling useQuery to re-render because of the new data, but because useQuery thinks it already rendered this data, it does not trigger an additional re-render.